# How to enable Module uploaded in different directory Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I upload my .info and .module file in sites/all/new/mymodule/ how can I enable this file on the admin page is it possible to enable it even though it's not uploaded in sites/all/modules/mymodule/ ? Im new in drupal thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't do that. According to Drupal official documentation:

> Download the module and extract it in the folder
>   **sites/all/modules/contrib**. It is recommended to place all third-party
>   modules in a subfolder called contrib.

All modules **should** be in the `sites/all/modules/` directory. (Exception for multisite installation.) It they're not, Drupal won't recognize it and you won't be able to enable it through the admin interface.

Please, take a look at [this page](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-7).

Comment: And custom modules should go in *sites/all/modules/custom*

Comment: Ok I'll always keep that in mind. Thanks for your help guys :)